# Finding duplicate records with different IDs within a table

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, self-join

I have a table as below:

```
ID     Product#   Service#   ServiceDate
1      100        122        2017-01-02
2      100        124        2017-03-02
3      122        133        2017-04-02        
100    100        122        2017-05-02
```

I need to find the records that have the same product# and service# but different IDs. For this, I wrote the code below:

```
Select * 
FROM MyTable as M1 Inner join 
MyTable as M2 on 
M1.Product#=M2.Product# and M1.Service#=M2.Service# and M1.ID!=M2.ID
```

However, I get duplicate results as such:

```
ID   Product# Service#  ServiceDate  ID   Product#  Service#  ServiceDate
1    100      122       2017-01-02   100  100       122       2017-05-02 
100  100      122       2017-05-02   1    100       122       2017-01-02
```

Any idea how to eliminate these duplicate rows? I need to see a result as such:

```
  ID   Product# Service#  ServiceDate  ID   Product#  Service#  ServiceDate
  1    100      122       2017-01-02   100  100       122       2017-05-02
```

Comment: Will you ever have more than two entries with the same product and service 
numbers in here?

Comment: @Eli Yes. It depends how many duplicates exist in the table. But it can be more than two.

Comment: Check out my answer below - it can work (I tested it) with more than two duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Select  * 
FROM MyTable as M1 
Inner join MyTable as M2 on M1.Product#=M2.Product# and M1.Service#=M2.Service# and M1.ID!=M2.ID
where m1.id < m2.id
```

**Explanation**: Your example shows both sides of each coin; by limiting it to having one of the ID's being less than the other, you'll automatically have just half of the records, effectively getting you all unique combinations.

**Bonus:** For fun, I tried to add one more duplicate row to your sample data set, and it worked just as expected.

Comment: @abahr you're very welcome. Please consider upvoting and accepting as the answer.

Comment: I did both but my up vote will not be visible to public since I am new here and my reputation is less than 15.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to return just two rows without the duplicate columns, replace

```
Select *
```

with

```
Select M1.*
```

Comment: I need to eliminate the duplicate rows not the columns. I added an example of the result that I am looking for in the question.